# Check for absence of contact

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm developing a puzzle platform game using Sprite Kit (and its physics engine). My player's physics body consists of a large hitbox covering most of the sprite, and a wheel with a pin joint anchored at the bottom of the hitbox. Rotation is added to the wheel to make the player move across the screen.

I need to know if the player is on the ground, or has fallen off a ledge; I know how to check for a physics body contact, but is it possible to check for an absence of contact (i.e. when the wheel leaves the ground)? I can't rely on comparing the Y position from the last frame as there are sloped surfaces that the player climbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact` to check if the wheel is no longer contacting the ground. Same principal as the `didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact` just in reverse.

Comment: Just a note to say I had to use a different approach in the end - my game world is tile-based, and `didEndContact` fires whenever the player leaves a tile (whether or not they move to another 'ground' tile). I now check for physics bodes underneath the left and right corners of the player using `physicsWorld.bodyAlongRayStart()` to detect if the player is standing on the ground.